# How to Remove Auto Code Completion using Junit in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

How can I get rid of these annoying auto-tags when creating test cases in intellij? I'd like to use basic formatting when filling the parameters for the assertEquals method specifically so it doesn't conflict with whatever my professor is using to run the test cases. Unfortunately whenever I start making a comment within the method parentheses, it automatically inserts what you see on the picture! Need to get rid of the expected and actual as in the screenshot below:

[image]

I know how to turn off code completion, but it doesn't seem to work for this specific case? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Although the IntelliJ allows you turn off the parameter name hint but it's not at all annoying. Any many new languages it is recommended to use the parameter naming. Java don't have such functionality so IntelliJ provides the same thing out of the box.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just didn't know the name for what I was trying to get rid of, I tried asking so many different questions on Google for at least an hour and I just couldn't find an answer, maybe this will help someone else along the way.

Comment: @BrighamRay If the answer helped, do accept it so that future readers might get help as well.

Comment: @Naman Will do, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Uncheck the *Show parameter name hints* option.

```
Preferences => Editor => General => Appearance => Uncheck the option
```

[image]